# method in asp.net webservice cannot connect to sharepoint site

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, sharepoint

i am trying to connect to sharepoint site from a method inside an asp.net web service but it is throwing the following exception:

> The Web application at `http://servername:1234` could not be found.
>   Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be
>   serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a
>   new request URL mapping to the intended application.

the code i'm using is only 3 lines:

```
  Dim sp As New SPSite("http://swd-ws2008:1234")
  Dim wen As SPWeb = sp.OpenWeb
  Dim list As SPList = wen.Lists("EmployeeFile")
```

when i run this same code from a windows desktop application, the connection works find and i'm able to retrieve data from sharepoint list however when i run it from asp.net it it not able to connect.

Comment: Check the application pool account under which your asp.net site is running, it might not have previliges to access the sharepoint site, either change the app pool user account or grant it access to the sharepoint site.

Comment: the web application is not deployed on iis yet, the error is showing in debug mode in visual studio

Comment: Permissions is one thing. Second can be that your web app that tries to connect to SharePoint Object Model is running on 32 bits application instead of 64 bit (i forget about this issue quite often)

Comment: The "WebDev"(Cassini) server runs under you local/domain account previliges, so make sure that user has access to the sharepoint site.

Comment: @Furqan: do you mean the local user?

Comment: the local user is already an administrator on the system

Comment: @AliTarhini, Yes I meant the same.